are there techniques for mixing signals in real-time?
If I have say, four signals that I want to mix together in real time, in order to avoid clipping, I am assuming the correct thing to do is divide each value by 4 and sum them?
for (int i=0; i<numSignals; i++) {
  output[n] += signals[i] / numSignals;
}

But I just keep thinking about this, if I had for example, 32 channels of audio, then any individual channel would be playing at 1/32 the volume...  Which I just am imaging if only one channel happened to be playing, the gain would have to be increased significantly to get to the level where it would be if there were no other channels being mixed.
Is this really the way it has to be?  Or are there techniques to merge samples without clipping, and without doing things like compression to maintain purity of the individual signals?

Does this answer your question? Algorithm(s) to mix audio signals without clipping

Standard process in audio is to do all the work in floating point (where you can't clip) and only deal with overflows or compression if you need to convert back to fixed point. There are many different ways of dealing with it and they depend on the reason why the conversion is necessary and the priorities of the specific application. For music production, this is called "mastering".


for (int i=0; i<numSignals; i++) {
 output[n] += signals[i] / numSignals;
}


The method you have mentioned in your code above will give you a clipping-free output provided the input does not have any clipping.
In general mixing can be performed in many ways. There is no hard rule to the weight - in your case $1/numSignals$ - to be assigned to each channel.
Mixing that you have mentioned in your code can be mathematically presented as
$$output[i] = \sum_{n=0}^{numSignals - 1}\alpha_n* signal_n[i]$$
A condition on the weights $$\sum_{n=0}^{numSignals - 1}|\alpha_n| = 1.0 $$ will ensure that the mixing will not result in clipping unless its already present in the original signals.
The weights chosen for mixing need not satisfy the condition mentioned above for all kinds of mixing.
Sometimes if the signal properties like maximum / minimum amplitude is known in advance it is possible to choose weights that do not satisfy the above properties yet do not result in clipping.
The weights $\alpha_n$ can be altered to ensure that a desired signal $signal_n[i]$ is more dominant in the resulting mixed output signal.
Example: Say we set all the weights to $0$ except for one weight $\alpha_k$ set to $1.0$ where $0 <= k < numSignals-1$ then $output[i]$ will be identical to $signal_k[i]$

So, what you are saying is, given a large enough set of mixed inputs with equal weights, you WILL arrive at a point where your master gain output will require being set to its MAX and even then, due to the large number of mixed signals, an individual input will never be as loud as it would have been had it not been mixed?

Yes. In the mixed signal the dominant sound depends on weights used for mixing and original signal strength / amplitude.
